# Is it possible to run classes.dex without apk in Android Runtime like Dalvik?

Tags: android, runtime, dalvik, dex, android-runtime

I know how to run classes.dex on DalvikVM via adb using command `adb shell dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/App.zip HelloWorld` where `App.zip` contains `classes.dex`, or `adb shell app_process -Djava.class.path=/sdcard/classes.dex /sdcard HelloWorld`.

So is it possible to execute classes.dex on Android Runtime (ART) like this, without any resource files and apk? I know ART use **dex2oat** to compile, is there any way to manually compile classes.dex into oat file, and execute the oat file later, by adb?

Answer (score 2):

You can still use both of those methods to on the latest versions of Android. The "dalvikvm" command is still present, although it's not actually dalvik, it's just a frontend for art.

Comment: I'm surprisingly happy to get it because I have been looking for the answer for a long time. I get the ART version when I input `adb shell dalvikvm -showversion`. Thank you for your prompt answer!